# VSCodium - Copies Double Empty Lines - Intermitently (Depending on Text Content)

Tags: linux, vscodium

I have a very annoying issue with VSCodium.

When you have a bunch of code and you try to copy it off of VSCodium, so CTRL+C, and then you paste it into another editor such as gedit, or another VSCodium tab, depending on what's inside the original text being copied, VSCodium inserts "an additional blank line" between the lines of code that have blank lines.

Please take a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Does anyone else also experience this or is it me only? I have tried deleting all .vscode-xx settings and dirs in my home dir and .config, so brand new profiles. I have tried doing the same thing with live linux ISOs and the same thing happens so it must be some sort of setting which I can't find  to turn off.

What's interesting is that if you have something like this:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

And you copy/paste that, it pastes as expected when pasting it with single lines between the lines.

How do we turn this feature (or is it a bug?) off, it's very annoying and I can't find a way to turn it off, there are so many options. I want to paste what I am copying, I don't want the editor inserting any extra empty lines that aren't there.

I have categorized this under vscodium and linux because that's what I use, vscodium and linux.